# R - reactable - groupBy - show totals on top

Tags: r, react-table

I have a question regarding `reactable` in `R`. I have a grouped df where som calculations has been made, eg relative numbers and sums. From my understanding it is possible to aggregate a grouped `reactable` using the built in functions max, mean etc. Instead I would like to display the rows named `show_top` instead of eg `colDef(aggregate = "max")`.

[I have noticed that you could create your own custom JS function](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html). Unfortunately I have no experience in JS.

```
colDef(
  aggregate = JS("
    function(values, rows) {
      // input:
      //  - values: an array of all values in the group
      //  - rows: an array of row info objects for all rows in the group
      //
      // output:
      //  - an aggregated value, e.g. a comma-separated list
      return values.join(', ')
    }
  ")
)
```

Please see below what I would like to achieve.

```
reactable(xy, groupBy = "col1")
```

[image]

```
structure(list(col1 = c("A", "B", "Tot", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "Tot", "Tot", "Tot"), col2 = c("show_top", "show_top", 
"show_top", "Type1", "Type2", "Type3", "Type1", "Type2", "Type3", 
"Type1", "Type2", "Type3"), inc = c(" 9.4 (38.7%)", "14.9 (61.3%)", 
"24.2 (100%)", " 3.7 (39.5%)", " 3.3 (35%)", " 2.4 (25.5%)", 
" 2.3 (15.2%)", " 4.6 (31%)", " 8.0 (53.8%)", " 6.0 (100%)", 
" 7.9 (100%)", "10.4 (100%)"), out = c(" 6.0 (39.6%)", " 9.1 (60.4%)", 
"15.1 (100%)", " 2.3 (38.7%)", " 2.1 (35.4%)", " 1.6 (25.9%)", 
" 0.7 (7.3%)", " 2.0 (21.5%)", " 6.5 (71.2%)", " 3.0 (100%)", 
" 4.1 (100%)", " 8.1 (100%)"), rel = c(0.638870535709061, 0.61502998385249, 
0.624251237892968, 0.626302127121007, 0.645747052829909, 0.648875413897266, 
0.296450202443903, 0.42683196642126, 0.813283715858821, 0.501288831579585, 
0.517981542096351, 0.775466939167642), rp = c(49.8379387690741, 
59.4422025881411, 55.229126405081, 46.132952162477, 51.5764509819408, 
53.8145905581141, 14.8399070194007, 32.048326903348, 137.425346172314, 
31.3269996331764, 39.887561604669, 105.790396392544)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 1):

While this is possible to achieve with a custom aggregate function, I think it'll be easier to use a custom aggregate cell renderer instead: https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/custom-rendering.html#javascript-render-function

Custom cell renderers have access to more information, like the name (or ID) of the column. The custom aggregate functions are more intended for simple operations on a list of values in a single column.

You can use a JavaScript function to customize the aggregated cell for all columns. For each aggregated cell, find the sub row for which the `col2` value is `"show_top"`. Then, return the value in that row corresponding to the current column.

Here's an example:

```
library(reactable)

reactable(
  xy,
  groupBy = "col1",
  defaultColDef = colDef(
    aggregated = JS("
      function(cellInfo) {
        for (var i = 0; i < cellInfo.subRows.length; i++) {
          var row = cellInfo.subRows[i]
          if (row.col2 === 'show_top') {
            return row[cellInfo.column.id]
          }
        }
      }
    ")
  )
)
```

[image]

The `cellInfo.subRows` and `cellInfo.column` properties are all documented in link above, if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Do you know if its possible to delete 'show_top' from the dropdown menu and only display the values on top?

Comment: You could hide the row with some conditional styling (using a `rowStyle` function to apply `display: none`, for example), but the row wouldn't be deleted. The group column will still show `(4)` rows. I think it'd make more sense to leave those summary rows out of the dataframe, and then summarize the groups using custom aggregate functions. There might be other ways to do this without having to know JavaScript, but that's a different question.